# How long ago did Adam live according to Islamic sources?

Tags: prophet-adam

There are some ahadith and Quranic verses that give details about how long certain people lived, and how long was between them, see e.g. [here](https://islamqa.info/en/20907). However, I'm not aware of whether or not there is a set of source texts that would let us calculate how long ago Adam supposedly lived. Does anyone know whether there is, and what the age of mankind turns out to be?

Comment: **<comments deleted>** As far as I'm concerned, dismissing Islamic beliefs as 'mythology' is blatant violation of "Be Nice" no matter how technically accurate it may be. If you disagree, feel free to take it to meta, I am done discussing it here.

Comment: Are you taking about Adam PBUH on earth or even before that in the garden? I highly doubt there’s an actual legitimate answer to this lol

Comment: I don't think there is any proof on that. We know Adam lived for 940 years. Reference hadith: https://sunnah.com/urn/680790